# Synchronizing global reference-counted resource with atomics -- is relaxed appropriate here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

I have a global reference-counted object `obj` that I want to protect from data races by using atomic operations:

```
T* obj;                  // initially nullptr
std::atomic<int> count;  // initially zero
```

My understanding is that I need to use `std::memory_order_release` after I write to `obj`, so that the other threads will be aware of it being created:

```
void increment()
{
    if (count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0)
        obj = std::make_unique<T>();

    count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
}
```

Likewise, I need to use `std::memory_order_acquire` when reading the counter, to ensure the thread has visibility of `obj` being changed:

```
void decrement()
{
    count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    if (count.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0)
        obj.reset();
}
```

I am not convinced that the code above is correct, but I'm not entirely sure why. I feel like after `obj.reset()` is called, there should be a `std::memory_order_release` operation to inform other threads about it. Is that correct?

Are there other things that can go wrong, or is my understanding of atomic operations in this case completely wrong?

Comment: Can `increment` be called concurrently? If yes, I think there's a data race on `obj`, right? Where multiple threads can load the counter, observe value `0`, and decide to assign a newly created `T` to `obj`, before any of those threads increments the counter?

Comment: Is creation of `T` cheap? If yes, there may be a way to implement it with atomics but when `obj` is not created yet, there could be many threads attempting to create it first. Only one would succeed and all others would have to destroy their `T` again.
If you want, I can work this out a bit more and post it as an answer. There may still be issues I haven't thought about yet but even then, it could be educational.

Answer (score 6):

It is wrong regardless of memory ordering.

As @MaartenBamelis pointed out for concurrent calling of `increment` the object is constructed twice. And the same is true for concurrent `decrement`: object is reset twice (which may result in double destructor call).

Note that there's disagreement between `T* obj;` declaration and using it as `unique_ptr` but neither raw pointer not unique pointer are safe for concurrent modification. In practice, `reset` or `delete` will check pointer for null, then delete and set it to null, and these steps are not atomic.

`fetch_add` and `fetch_sub` are fetch and op instead of just op for a reason: if you don't use the value observed during operation, it is likely to be a race.

Comment: I see, yes -- I didn't think this through properly. Is it possible at all to avoid double-creation and double-destruction of `obj` by only using atomic operations? Or is a mutex required in this particular situation?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, if you only wanted to free on reaching count zero - then it is doable. Construction on demand, when growing the count from zero - cannot be lock free. (You may spin on an atomic, to avoid mutexes, but it is still not lock-free)

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Spinning on a mutex would make it _lock_-free but not _wait_-free, right?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis, hm, I'm not sure. I thought that blocking on a spinlock is still blocking, and it means there may be no progress under certain circumstances, so it was not lock free.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: No thread can proceed with its work until the `make_unique` has completed, and any solution will have to enforce that somehow.  So if whatever thread is doing that should get arbitrarily delayed, none of the others make any progress; they will be somehow stuck, whether in a mutex block or a spin loop or what have you.  That is, by definition, not lock free.

Comment: @NateEldredge Makes sense, agreed!

Answer (score 5):

This code is inherently racey. If two threads call `increment` at the same time when `count` is initially `0`, both will see `count` as `0`, and both will create `obj` (and race to see which copy is kept; given `unique_ptr` has no special threading protections, terrible things can happen if two of them set it at once).

If two threads `decrement` at the same time (holding the last two references), and finish the `fetch_sub` before either calls `load`, both will `reset` `obj` (also bad).

And if a `decrement` finishes the `fetch_sub` (to `0`), then another thread `increment`s before the `decrement` `load` occurs, the `increment` will see the `count` as `0` and reinitialize. Whether the object is cleared after being replaced, or replaced after being cleared, or some horrible mixture of the two, will depend on whether `increment`'s `fetch_add` runs before or after `decrement`'s `load`.

In short: If you find yourself using two separate atomic operations on the same variable, and testing the result of one of them (without looping, as in a compare and swap loop), you're wrong.

More correct code would look like:

```
void increment()             // Still not safe
{
   // acquire is good for the != 0 case, for a later read of obj
   // or would be if the other writer did a release *after* constructing an obj
    if (count.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire) == 0)
        obj = std::make_unique<T>();
}

void decrement()
{
    if (count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acquire) == 1)
        obj.reset();
}
```

but even then it's not reliable; there's no guarantee that, when `count` is `0`, two threads couldn't call `increment`, *both* of them `fetch_add` at once, and while exactly one of them is guaranteed to see the `count` as `0`, said `0`-seeing thread might end up delayed while the one that saw it as `1` assumes the object exists and uses it before it's initialized.

I'm not going to swear there's no mutex-free solution here, but dealing with the issues involved with atomics is almost certainly not worth the headache.

It might be possible to confine the mutex to inside the `if()` branches, but taking a mutex is also an atomic RMW operation (and not much more than that for a good lightweight implementation) so this doesn't necessarily help a huge amount.  If you need really good read-side scaling, you'd want to look into something like [RCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update) instead of a ref-count, to allow readers to truly be read-only, not contending with other readers.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence alone. Your "more correct" snippet looks deceivingly correct indeed, well done for pointing out it is still racey on `obj`!

Comment: The last example was very helpful, I can see how subtle the issues can get in this case. I guess that maybe making `obj` a `std::atomic<T*>` itself could lead to a possible solution, but I'm quite convinced it is not worth the headache...

Comment: I think the best compare and contrast is with `std::shared_ptr` and `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` it's worth noting that while the former is thread safe from a *reference count* perspective it is not thread safe from a construction perspective. Peeking at a few implementations of the latter they most definitely use mutexes to guard construction and initialization. At least one implementation of the former does use atomics but does not use a mutex to guard destruction (because it's already at zero and thus invalid to use at that point).

Comment: *I'm not going to swear there's no mutex-free solution here* - Probably true; anything safe with pure atomics would probably amount to a hand-rolled spinlock.  But you *may* be able to keep mutex out of the fast path, only using it when inside the `if` branch.  (Still need an atomic RMW on the ref count, like `std::shared_ptr`.)

Comment: If not for `decrement`, this would be the same problem as a `static` local var with a non-constant initializer, where the fast path for reads is just an acquire load of a guard variable.  Only if it's not already initted, then mutex so one thread assigns. https://godbolt.org/z/KGdnGEnse shows what GCC does.

Comment: I don't think your `memory_order_release` makes any sense for `increment`; it might as well be `relaxed` since you still need a mutex inside that `if`, and it provides synchronization.  Since you're not going to read the old value of `obj` after that, I don't think `acquire` is useful either.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yeah, I figure some weirdo variation on double-checked locking (except with reference counts and a concept of releasing resources and perhaps reacquiring them later) would allow you to make this work. I thought it out as far as knowing it would need both the count and pointer to be `atomic`s, and would need a mutex on top of that. Then I considered how you'd handle ensuring the mutex was protecting weird cases involving races between final `decrement` of an existing object and an `increment` coming in that might prevent that decrement or reinit later and threw up my hands. :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yeah, the memory orders here are garbage from copy-pasting bits of OP's code rather than retyping (I wasn't really thinking about them; no memory order would fix this without a mutex, and with a mutex, the memory order wouldn't matter, unless we were doing conditional mutex use, and as I said, I've thrown up my hands there, not worth the trouble unless the OP can prove it's limiting them to mutex unconditionally).

Comment: I made an edit to point out that `acquire` solves half the problem, or would if there was a `release` after writing `obj`.  I think that's more useful than showing `release` in a position where it doesn't help at all.  (At least I think it doesn't.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a simple way of implementing a reference-counted resource with atomics. Maybe there's some clever way that I haven't thought of yet, but in my experience, clever does not equal readable.

My advice would be to implement it first using a mutex. Then you simply lock the mutex, check the reference count, do whatever needs to be done, and unlock again. It's guaranteed correct:

```
std::mutex mutex;
int count;
std::unique_ptr<T> obj;

void increment()
{
    auto lock = std::scoped_lock{mutex};
    if (++count == 1) // Am I the first reference?
        obj = std::make_unique<T>();
}

void decrement()
{
    auto lock = std::scoped_lock{mutex};
    if (--count == 0) // Was I the last reference?
        obj.reset();
}
```

Although at this point, I would just use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of managing the reference count myself:

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::weak_ptr<T> obj;

std::shared_ptr<T> acquire()
{
    auto lock = std::scoped_lock{mutex};
    auto sp = obj.lock();
    if (!sp)
        obj = sp = std::make_shared<T>();
    return sp;
}
```

I believe this also makes it safe when exceptions may be thrown when constructing the object.

Mutexes are surprisingly performant, so I expect that locking code is plenty quick unless you have a highly specialized use case where you need code to be lock-free.

Comment: You may be able to confine the mutex to the `if` branch, avoiding it for the fast path.  (If you keep the atomic RMW, with acquire semantics).  If not for `decrement`, this would be the same problem as a `static` local var with a non-constant initializer, where the fast path for reads is just an acquire load of a guard variable.  Only if it's not already initted, then mutex so one thread assigns. https://godbolt.org/z/KGdnGEnse shows what GCC does.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point. I recall having implemented such a pattern at work a few years ago. I had to lazily initialize members but the code that did so could be invoked concurrently. I had an atomic flag and went over to locking if it indicated no initialization was done yet. If the flag was set, it was just a read without locking (as per your comment).

Comment: Note: `std::lock_guard` (or in C++17 and higher, `std::scoped_lock`) might be slightly lower overhead than `std::unique_lock` (and clarifies to the reader that you're definitely not doing complicated unlock/relock stuff), so you may as well use them.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The overhead of `std::unique_lock` is an if-check in the destructor, to check if the mutex has already been manually unlocked? Or is it someone else?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: In theory, it might be nothing (at least initially, IIRC, the implementation of both was the same for some compilers, and with optimizations on, many will recognize a pure RAII use of `std::unique_lock` and generate identical code). But yes, if the implementations are separate, and the optimizer misses something, the cost is mostly just unnecessary checks. The main benefit is to the programmer; if you see `std::lock_guard`, you don't need to wonder if the lock is released in that scope.